# Spring boot Application running fine on intellij idea but not working on terminal

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, javabeans

Spring boot Application is running fine on intellij idea but on running the same jar file on terminal it shows the following error:

```
 ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'alertController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'alertService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'alertService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'alertRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alertRepository' defined in org.example.repository.AlertRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://
```

Here is pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version> <!-- spring boot version number -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AlertSystemBE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the spring Application:

```
package org.example;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                        .maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the controller class:

```
package org.example.controller;
import org.example.Model.Alert;
import org.example.Model.Comment;
import org.example.service.AlertService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class AlertController {
    @Autowired
    private AlertService alertService;

    @GetMapping("/alert")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllAlerts(){
        List<Alert> alerts;
        alerts = alertService.getAllAlerts();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Alert>>(alerts, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
@GetMapping("/alert/assignto/{assignedTo}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAlertsByAssignedTo(@PathVariable String assignedTo) {
        List<Alert> alertOp=alertService.getAlertsByAssignedTo(Integer.parseInt(assignedTo));
        if(alertOp!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(alertOp, HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No alert Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
 @GetMapping("/alert/timeofarrival/{timeOfArrival}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAlertsByTimeOfArrival(@PathVariable("timeOfArrival") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date timeOfArrival) throws ParseException {
        List<Alert> alertOp=alertService.getAlertsByTimeOfArrival(timeOfArrival);
        if(alertOp!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(alertOp, HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No alert Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Here is the service class:

```
@Service
public class AlertService {
    @Autowired
    private AlertRepository alertRepo;
    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository commentRepo;
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;
    public List<Alert> getAllAlerts() {
        List<Alert> alerts = alertRepo.findAll();
        return alerts;
    }
public List<Alert> getAlertsByAssignedTo(int assignedTo){
        return alertRepo.findAllAlertByAssignedTo(assignedTo);
    }
public List<Alert> getAlertsByTimeOfArrival(Date timeOfArrival) throws ParseException {
//        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//        Date date1=formatter.parse(timeOfArrival);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(timeOfArrival);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Date start = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date end = cal.getTime();
        List<Alert> alerts= alertRepo.findAllAlertByTimeOfArrivalBetween(start,end);
        return alerts;
    }
}
```

Here is the repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface AlertRepository extends MongoRepository<Alert, String> {
List<Alert> findAllAlertByAssignedTo(int assignedTo);
List<Alert> findAllAlertByTimeOfArrivalBetween(Date start, Date end);
}
```

Here is the model class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

//@EntityScan
@Document(collection = "Alert")
public class Alert {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull(message = "Title can't be empty")
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String trigger_timespan;
    private String sourcegroups;
//    private String queryTerms;
    private List<String> recent_events;
    @DBRef
    private List<Comment> comments;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date timeOfArrival=new Date();
    @CreatedDate
    private Date timeOfFixed;
    private int assignedTo;
    private String fixed;
    private String criticality;
    private String type;//eg: loggly or database alert
    private String area;

    public void setFixed(String fixed) {
        this.fixed = fixed;
    }
}
```

This is `application.properties` file:

```
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGO_DB}
spring.data.mongodb.database=${DATABASE_NAME}
gmail.email=${GMAIL_ID}
gmail.app.password=${GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD}
```

This is `.env` file:

```
MONGO_DB=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.ldofpxl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
DATABASE_NAME=Master
```

I tried checking the MANIFEST.MF file which has the following specification:

```
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Implementation-Title: AlertSystemBE
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: org.example.Application
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.5.2
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

The java version installed on my local is also 11

```
PS C:\Users\mansi.keshari\Downloads\demo2\demo2\Alert_Polling> java --version
openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (build 11.0.18+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.18.10.1 (build 11.0.18+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I tried `mvn clean package` and `mvn clean install` also but that too did not work.

Help me find a solution. I checked stack overflow and ChatGPT but cannot find a solution.

Comment: where are you defining connection string to mongo server and how does it look like. Maybe you have some default config in intellij but you forgot to put it into `application.properties|yaml`?

Comment: @MansiKeshari pls delete your above comment which have srv url. (Note : please do not share any personalize url, username, password in public.)

Comment: Yes I provided the altered one only and now i have updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a `.env` file for Spring Boot, is it a IDE file?

Have you tried defining the environment variables before launching?

Something like this:

```
export MONGO_DB=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.ldofpxl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
export DATABASE_NAME=Master
java -jar AlertSystemBE.jar
```

Comment: It's still showing the same error. I just want to hide the credentials when I push it to github. I also tried adding the application.properties file in .gitgnore file but that didn't help. Adding .env file in .gitignore did hide the credentials but then the application is not running on terminal